# How to migrate upload object workflows to Direct to S3 approach?

Tags: autodesk-forge

I am using the [forge-api-dotnet-client](https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-api-dotnet-client) package to upload objects to the OSS collection with my webapp. With the old object endpoints being deprecated soon, I am assuming that the `ObjectsApi.UploadObject()` method will become obsolete. Is the `ObjectsApi.UploadSignedResource()` method simplest way to implement the direct to S3 approach?

I see that [here](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/data-management-oss-object-storage-service-migrating-direct-s3-approach) that the Direct to S3 approach seems to be a more complicated multipart upload, but I can not find a clear example showing how to implement the process in C#.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This code snippet should help you https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-api-dotnet-client/blob/3ed6f137cc693414c506bd703e2d2044a0495a0c/DirectS3Advanced/Program.cs#L269
If not let me know.

Comment: Can you explain the purpose of the `verifyServerObjectsSha1()` method? Is it necessary to perform this step after uploading a file?

Comment: verifyServerObjectsSha1  - checks if the hash value [sha1] of object on S3 and computed hash of data [which has been uploaded to s3] on disk is same or different
https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/data/v2/reference/http/buckets-:bucketKey-objects-GET/
That step is not required to complete the uploading a file to OSS S3.

Comment: Great, thanks so much for the help! This snippet is exactly what I was searching for!